# How to get function output to add columns to my Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a function that produces an output like so when I pass it a name:

`W2V('aamir')`

```
array([ 0.12135 , -0.99132 ,  0.32347 ,  0.31334 ,  0.97446 , -0.67629 ,
        0.88606 , -0.11043 ,  0.79434 ,  1.4788  ,  0.53169 ,  0.95331 ,
       -1.1883  ,  0.82438 , -0.027177,  0.70081 ,  0.87467 , -0.095825,
       -0.5937  ,  1.4262  ,  0.2187  ,  1.1763  ,  1.6294  ,  0.91717 ,
       -0.086697,  0.16529 ,  0.19095 , -0.39362 , -0.40367 ,  0.83966 ,
       -0.25251 ,  0.46286 ,  0.82748 ,  0.93061 ,  1.136   ,  0.85616 ,
        0.34705 ,  0.65946 , -0.7143  ,  0.26379 ,  0.64717 ,  1.5633  ,
       -0.81238 , -0.44516 , -0.2979  ,  0.52601 , -0.41725 ,  0.086686,
        0.68263 , -0.15688 ], dtype=float32)
```

I have a data frame that has an index `Name` and a single column `Y`:

`df1`

```
    Y
Name    
aamir   0
aaron   0
... ...
zulema  1
zuzana  1
```

I wish to run my function on each value of `Name` and have it create columns like so:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
Name                                                                                    
aamir   0.12135 -0.99132    0.32347 0.31334 0.97446 -0.67629    0.88606 -0.11043    0.794340    1.47880 ... 0.647170    1.56330 -0.81238    -0.445160   -0.29790    0.52601 -0.41725    0.086686    0.68263 -0.15688
aaron   -1.01850    0.80951 0.40550 0.09801 0.50634 0.22301 -1.06250    -0.17397    -0.061715   0.55292 ... -0.144960   0.82696 -0.51106    -0.072066   0.43069 0.32686 -0.00886    -0.850310   -1.31530    0.71631
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
zulema  0.56547 0.30961 0.48725 1.41000 -0.76790    0.39908 0.86915 0.68361 -0.019467   0.55199 ... 0.062091    0.62614 0.44548 -0.193820   -0.80556    -0.73575    -0.30031    -1.278900   0.24759 -0.55541
zuzana  -1.49480    -0.15111    -0.21853    0.77911 0.44446 0.95019 0.40513 0.26643 0.075182    -1.34340    ... 1.102800    0.51495 1.06230 -1.587600   -0.44667    1.04600 -0.38978    0.741240    0.39457 0.22857
```

What I have done is real messy, but works:

```
names = df1.index.to_list()

Lst = []
for name in names:
    Lst.append(W2V(name).tolist())
wv_df = pd.DataFrame(index=names, data=Lst)
wv_df.index.name = "Name"
wv_df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df1 = df1.merge(wv_df, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

I am hoping there is a way to use .apply() or similar but I have not found how to do this.  I am looking for an efficient way.

Update:

I modified my function to do like so:

```
if isinstance(w, pd.core.series.Series):
        w = w.to_string()
```

Although this appears to work at first, the data is wrong.  If I pass `aamir` to my function you can see the result.  Yet when I do it with apply the numbers are totally different:

```
df1

    Name    Y
0   aamir   0
1   aaron   0
... ... ...
7942    zulema  1
7943    zuzana  1

df3 = df1.reset_index().drop('Y', axis=1).apply(W2V, axis=1, result_type='expand')

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
0   0.075014    0.824769    0.580976    0.493415    0.409894    0.142214    0.202602    -0.599501   -0.213184   -0.142188   ... 0.627784    0.136511    -0.162938   0.095707    -0.257638   0.396822    0.208624    -0.454204   0.153140    0.803400
1   0.073664    0.868665    0.574581    0.538951    0.394502    0.134773    0.233070    -0.639365   -0.194892   -0.110557   ... 0.722513    0.147112    -0.239356   -0.046832   -0.237434   0.321494    0.206583    -0.454038   0.251605    0.918388
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
7942    -0.002117   0.894570    0.834724    0.602266    0.327858    -0.003092   0.197389    -0.675813   -0.311369   -0.174356   ... 0.690172    -0.085517   -0.000235   -0.214937   -0.290900   0.361734    0.290184    -0.497177   0.285071    0.711388
7943    -0.047621   0.850352    0.729225    0.515870    0.439999    0.060711    0.226026    -0.604846   -0.344891   -0.128396   ... 0.557035    -0.048322   -0.070075   -0.265775   -0.330709   0.281492    0.304157    -0.552191   0.281502    0.750304
7944 rows × 50 columns
```

You can see that the first row is `aamir` and the first value (column 0) my function returns is 0.1213 (You can see this at the top of my post).  Yet with apply that appears to be 0.075014

EDIT:

It appears it passes in `Name    aamir` rather than `aamir`.  How can I get it to just send the Name itself `aamir`?

Comment: I don't think there is a builtin way to iterate through the rows of a dataframe and create new columns for that record

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch I believe with Dataframes apply() method using the result_type='expand' it can be done.  I just haven't been able to get it to work, see this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this using `map` and `np.vstack` with a dataframe constructor then `join`:

```
df.join(pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(df.index.map(W2V)), index=df.index))
```

Output:

```
   Y  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
A  0  4  0  2  1  0  0  0  0  3  3
B  1  4  0  0  4  4  3  4  3  4  3
C  2  1  5  5  5  3  3  1  3  5  0
D  3  3  5  1  3  4  2  3  1  0  1
E  4  4  0  2  4  4  0  3  3  4  2
F  5  4  3  5  1  0  2  3  2  5  2
G  6  4  5  2  0  0  2  4  3  4  3
H  7  0  2  5  2  3  4  3  5  3  1
I  8  2  2  0  1  4  2  4  1  0  4
J  9  0  2  3  5  0  3  0  2  4  0
```

Using @Vitalizzare function:

```
def W2V(name: str) -> np.ndarray:
    low, high, size = 0, 5, 10
    rng = np.random.default_rng(abs(hash(name)))
    return rng.integers(low, high, size, endpoint=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': np.arange(10)}, index = [*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have some function which transforms a string into a vector of a fixed size, for example:

```
import numpy as np

def W2V(name: str) -> np.ndarray:
    low, high, size = 0, 5, 10
    rng = np.random.default_rng(abs(hash(name)))
    return rng.integers(low, high, size, endpoint=True)
```

Also a data frame is given with a meaningful index and junk data:

```
import pandas as pd

names = pd.Index(['aamir','aaron','zulema','zuzana'], name='Name')
df = pd.DataFrame(index=names).assign(Y=0)
```

When we apply some function to a `DataFrame` along columns, i.e. `axis=1`, its argument is gonna be a row as `Series` wich name is an index of the row. So we could do something like this:

```
output = df.apply(lambda row: W2V(row.name), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

With `result_type='expand'`, returned vectors will be transformed into columns, which is the required output.

---

P.S. As an option:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({n: W2V(n) for n in names}, orient='index')
```

---

P.P.S. IMO The behavior you describe means that your function can operate not only on `str`, but also on some common sequence, for example on a `Series` of strings. In case of the code:

```
df.reset_index().drop('Y', axis=1).apply(W2V, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

the function `W2V` receives not `"a name"` as a string but `pd.Series(["a name"])`. If we do not check the type of the passed parameter inside the function, then we can get a silent error, which in this case appears as different output data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is any better than the other suggestions, but I would use apply to create another *n*-column dataframe (where *n* is the length of the array returned by the W2V function) and then concatenate it to the original dataframe.

This first section generates toy versions of your `W2V` function and your dataframe.

```
# substitute your W2V function for this:
n = 5
def W2V(name: str):
    return [random() for i in range(n)]

# substitute your 2-column dataframe for this:
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name':['aamir', 'aaron', 'zulema', 'zuzana'],
                         'Y': [0, 0, 1, 1]},
                   index=list(range(4)))
```

`df1` is

```
     Name  Y
0   aamir  0
1   aaron  0
2  zulema  1
3  zuzana  1
```

You want to make a second dataframe that applies `W2V` to every name in the first dataframe.  To generate your column numbers, I'm just using a list comprehension that generates [0, 1, ... n], where n is the length of the array returned by W2V.

```
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(W2V(x['Name']),
                                    index=[i for i in range(n)]),
                axis=1)
```

My random-valued `df2` is

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.242761  0.415253  0.940213  0.074455  0.444372
1  0.935781  0.968155  0.850091  0.064548  0.737655
2  0.204053  0.845252  0.967767  0.352254  0.028609
3  0.853164  0.698195  0.292238  0.982009  0.402736
```

Then concatenate the new dataframe to the old one:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

`df3` is

```
     Name  Y         0         1         2         3         4
0   aamir  0  0.242761  0.415253  0.940213  0.074455  0.444372
1   aaron  0  0.935781  0.968155  0.850091  0.064548  0.737655
2  zulema  1  0.204053  0.845252  0.967767  0.352254  0.028609
3  zuzana  1  0.853164  0.698195  0.292238  0.982009  0.402736
```

Alternatively, you could do both steps in one line as:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df1, 
                 df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(W2V(x['Name']), 
                                               index=[i for i in range(n)]), 
                           axis=1)], 
                axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going off the names being the axis, and there being a useless column called 0. I think this may be the solution, no way to know without your function or the names

```
df.reset_index().drop(0, axis=1).apply(my_func, axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do simply:

```py
newdf = pd.DataFrame(df.index.to_series().apply(w2v).tolist(), index=df.index)
```

#### Example

To start with, let us make some function `w2v(name)`. In the following, we compute a consistent hash of any string. Then we use that hash as a (temporary) seed for `np.random`, and then draw a random vector `size=50`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def temp_seed(seed):
    state = np.random.get_state()
    np.random.seed(seed)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        np.random.set_state(state)
        

mask = (1 << 32) - 1

def w2v(name, size=50):
    fingerprint = int(pd.util.hash_array(np.array([name])))
    with temp_seed(fingerprint & mask):
        return np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size)
```

For instance:

```py
>>> w2v('aamir')
array([ 0.65446901, -0.92765123, -0.78188552, -0.62683782, -0.23946784,
        0.31315156,  0.22802972, -0.96076167,  0.62577993, -0.59024811,
        0.76365736,  0.93033898, -0.56155296,  0.4760905 , -0.92760642,
        0.00177959, -0.22761559,  0.81929959,  0.21138229, -0.49882747,
       -0.97637984, -0.19452496, -0.91354933,  0.70473533, -0.30394358,
       -0.47092087, -0.0329302 , -0.93178517,  0.79118799,  0.98286834,
       -0.16024194, -0.02793147, -0.52251214, -0.70732759,  0.10098142,
       -0.24880249,  0.28930319, -0.53444863,  0.37887522,  0.58544068,
        0.85804119,  0.67048213,  0.58389158, -0.19889071, -0.04281131,
       -0.62506126,  0.42872395, -0.12821543, -0.52458052, -0.35493892])
```

Now, we use the expression given as solution:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([0,0,1,1], index=['aamir', 'aaron', 'zulema', 'zuzana'])
newdf = pd.DataFrame(df.index.to_series().apply(w2v).tolist(), index=df.index)

>>> newdf
              0         1         2         3         4         5         6    ...
aamir   0.654469 -0.927651 -0.781886 -0.626838 -0.239468  0.313152  0.228030   ...
aaron  -0.380524 -0.850608 -0.914642 -0.578885  0.177975 -0.633761 -0.736234   ...
zulema -0.250957  0.882491 -0.197833 -0.707652  0.754575  0.731236 -0.770831   ... 
zuzana -0.641296  0.065898  0.466784  0.652776  0.391865  0.918761  0.022798   ...
```